# AJAX (post method) data type advantages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

I have this Jquery code in front end:

```
        var person = { Name: name, Email: email, Phone: phone };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: serviceURL,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(person) ,
            traditional : true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
```

which calls the following ASP.Net MVC controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(Person person)
    {
       // Do something with person 
    }
```

Person class is :

```
  public class Person 
  {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public string Phone { get; set; }
  }
```

so my question is what is the less dependency causing AJAX post data type ?
like if I used person class formater of my controler , if after 2 month I desired to add new fildes I will have to edit the class , I will depend on the class.
so using application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 datatype might be better and less dependency causing ? since I will deal only with key value pair ?
what is the best strategy to have most flexible code or even if some approach is better than the other in another way. as I'm willing to become more mature and write code that will cause less problems in the future.

> Update:    since my question was not clear , I will reform it,  when
>   to prefer on data     type on other? what are advantages of each one
>   give us? like if there is more     than one data type to send the data
>   there should be practical cases in which     one is better than other,
>   I'm concerned to discover this advantages.

Comment: Not clear what your asking. You can simply delete `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and use `data: person` to use the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` but either way your posting name/value pairs (just in different formats). And if you have generated you view correctly, then you can just use `data: $('form').serialize();`

Comment: but in this case I get strong typing by just using controller parameter to read the posted value inside the controller, the I will read the data from person class instance attribute instead of getting it from request by key value pair

Comment: Yes I know, but what are you asking? Both methods send name/value pairs - it makes no difference at all.

Comment: I'm asking about when to prefer on data type on other? what are advantages of each one ?

Comment: As far as the `DefaultModelBinder` goes, it uses the `FormValueProvider` for `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` which is fractionally less processing than the `JsonValueProviderFactory` used when its `'application/json'` (but its insignificant)

Comment: can you give general comparison between all sending data types like the XML one based on your experience please ?  I think there shall be some cases when one data type will become more handy than other, but again I could be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154694/discussion-between-alphas-supremum-and-stephen-muecke).